# Boolean field added to crm is not saved

Tags: python, crm, odoo-11

I inherited the crm.lead model and added a computed Boolean field, unfortunately it is not saved in the db and consequently I cannot operate on the view. This field if true adds a string to the kanban.

```
    <record id="crm_case_kanban_view_leads_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">crm.lead.kanban (in agreements_crm)</field>
        <field name="model">crm.lead</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="crm.crm_case_kanban_view_leads"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name="activity_ids" position="after">
                <field name="need_agreements"/>
            </field>

            <xpath expr="//div[@class='oe_kanban_content']" position="after">
                <!-- <t t-if="record.need_agreements.value == false">
                    <p>No Needs Agreement Creation</p>
                </t> -->
                <t t-if="record.need_agreements.value">
                    <p>Needs Agreement Creation</p>
                </t>                
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
```

I also tried adding store = True but the results were singleton errors on the computed method

```py
    def _compute_need_agreements(self):
        type_id = ''

        for tag in self.tag_ids:
            if self.env['agreements.type'].search([('agreements_label_ids.name', '=', tag.name)]):
                type_id = self.env['agreements.type'].search([('agreements_label_ids.name', '=', tag.name)])
                break


        if self.stage_id.name == "Won" and type_id and self.agreements_count < 1:
            # for record in self:
                # record.need_agreements = True
            record.write({'need_agreements':True})

        else:
            # for record in self:
            record.write({'need_agreements':False})
```

After several tests I still can't use it, this is the first time that I get this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by changing my approach

```
<p attrs="{'invisible':[('need_agreements', '=', False)]}" style="color:Red;">Needs Agreement Creation</p>
```

using attrs invisible I was able to solve my problem, I don't understand why the Qweb conditions didn't help me